# Software and Updates option is not in System Settings in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: 18.04, settings

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 from 17.10, I am not able to see a Software and Updates option in System Settings.

Where is it?

Comment: Can you run it via terminal: `software-properties-gtk` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 from scratch. I cannot find a software and updates option in system settings either, but the option is available under the **Show Applications** menu as **Software & Updates** app.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find it either, I have installed it using

`sudo apt install software-properties-gtk`

then, you can open it from the terminal using `software-properties-gtk` or open it from the application menu, under the name **Software & Updates** app.